# Creating waterfall plot in Qt

Tags: qt, plot, waterfall

I need to have a waterfall plot in Qt GUI. But I can't find any appropriate widget.

I want to display input data (from LAN) 50 times in one second into waterfall plot.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to implement it yourself using e.g. [QwtPlotSpectrogram](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_spectrogram.html) from [Qwt - Qt Widgets for Technical Applications](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) open source project whose [license](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtlicense.html) is LGPL with some exceptions. I haven't used the library myself so can't give any further assistance but the project seems to be active. By googling I noticed some implementations based on QwtPlotSpectrogram in [GitHub](https://github.com/), no idea of their quality level though.